# How to collapse all trees in htop?

Tags: linux, unix, htop

I would like to be able to collapse all the trees in the default view of htop. Is there a way to achieve that at once, instead of selecting every tree and hitting F6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Possible as of 3.1.0 (not yet in all distributions)

As of `htop --version` **3.1.0**, you can in fact toggle-collapse all branches of the tree view (<kbd>F5</kbd>) using hotkey <kbd>*</kbd> (asterisk). The release happened only on 2021-09-21, so most 2022 linux distributions (except those with rolling releases) are about to receive the updated version with their next release.

For example, the [Ubuntu package overview for `htop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=htop) shows that

- ❌ Ubuntu 21.10 (impish) and 22.04 LTS (jammy) both stick to version 3.0.5 and only
- ✅ **Ubuntu 22.10 (kinetic) ships with 3.2.1**.

---

And just for completeness sake:

- Collapsing and expanding invidivual tree nodes was/remains possible using <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd>
- To review all key bindings in your version of htop, simply enter the help screen (<kbd>?</kbd> or <kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd>)

Comment: Works with 3.2.1, just tested it. Just to add that you first need to press F5 to create the tree hierarchy and then press asterisk to collapse all trees.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK "t" is the hotkey for expansion and collapsing tree view in htop.

Comment: Worked for me. Dunno why it got a downvote :/ ?

Comment: For me it switches between tree and list so it doesn't really collapse.

Comment: But that *is* callapsing Would you rather kill a process (tree)?

Comment: toggle between tree/list isn't what's being asked for here.

Comment: `t` is a switch to disable/enable tree view, not to collapse tree

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `*` key

This was implemented in version 3.0.5 (2021-01-12)

- https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/issues/68
- https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/pull/525

Comment: Looks like it hasn't been released just yet, but apparently the + key works to collapse individual line entries.

Comment: `=` seems to be doing the same job

Answer (score 2):

---

It is still not implented. Moreover, F5/F6 were "killed".

Besides, +/- do not work from keypad. As a result, the whole idea of tree-view became useless (as for me it is the only possible way to represent a lot of processes)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1102158)

Answer (score -7):

I don't know about any option to expand/collapse individual branches in htop's tree view (or any other ncurses-based software¹). I would suggest not to presume things of text-based applications from things you have learned from graphical ones².

You can (only) enable/disable tree based view using F5.

Notes:

1. I've got somehow used to the different design pattern in text-based (DOS era and ncurses or similar based Unix ones) and graphical applications. This collapse tree thing was, in my eyes, a thing invented in Windows.
2. I would suggest anyone who want to get used to Unix systems disable their GUI for at least a week and learn things again from the bottom up.

Comment: Is `aptitude` curse-based?  That certainly opens/closes subtrees.