# How to Collapse the View of **ALL** instances of all applications

Tags: htop

After executing the `htop` command, you can press `F5` (or `t`) in order to see the tree view. But how do I collapse the tree for having a *higher order view only* instead of the long list of all processes?

For example, I would like to see how much of my memory is being used by Firefox and not by its infinitely many subprocesses. There is already this [StackExchange Post](https://superuser.com/questions/855016/how-to-collapse-all-trees-in-htop), but it's quite old, so maybe there has been advances on this topic since then?

Is there an alternative to `htop` that does have this feature?

Comment: Press <F5> or <t> a second time to return to the previously selected view.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how that relates to the problem.

Comment: Then your question is not clear.

Comment: I disagree completely. I don't want to *go back to the previously selected view*, but have an even more collapsed view of the applications being run. I've even mentioned an example use case and a related StackExchange Post.

Comment: Have you found any way to collapse all? or an alternative?

Comment: Not yet. I've been using Windows 99% of the time lately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to collapse all trees in htop?](https://superuser.com/questions/855016/how-to-collapse-all-trees-in-htop)